# Count click on iframe PHP

Tags: php, iframe, count, click

I have a file with title ad.php and contains

```
<a href="http://www.google.ro"><img src="bannerimg.png"></a>
```

and in another file i have:

```
<iframe src="ad.php"></iframe>
```

Question is how to count click on iframe!

Comment: What do you mean by "count click"?  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I want to count click and insert into database

Comment: go on http://api.jquery.com/click/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ read all you need about making XMLHTTPRequest. google ajax request and find thousand of example on how to save data in a mysql database with php (http://woork.blogspot.it/2007/10/insert-record-into-database-using-ajax.html first link by googling "ajax php save") try to implement it yourself. This should be a place where people ask for enlightment not for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do this if using javascript....

```
var clik = 0;

$('#myframe').click(function(){
clik++
alert(clik);
});
```

**UPDATE WITH AJAX**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $('#myframe').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

 $.ajax({
 url : "countclick.php",
 success: function(){
    alert('done');
   }
 });

 });
 });
```

Then in your php file  `countclick.php` you just retrieve the current value from database, and increment it and update.

Or just execute an increment query directly, without retrieving current value
Im assuming you know how to do that in php/mysql , so Im not gonna post that part

Comment: And with ajax/post pass how is write ?

Comment: It doesn't matter... as long as you attach a click handler to your iframe, you trigger a post to the php page....you can then just query the database, retrieve the current count, increment and update...you don't need to actually count with javascript, you can do it server side.  You can then just run an increment update like so.....UPDATE table SET clickcount = clickcount + 1 WHERE [...]  You will however...need to know which banner to update.  You can retrieve the id with jquery, and post that to the php page, which you would pass to your WHERE statement, to update the correct banner

Answer (score 0):

You would have to catch the click event somewhere on the client side (in JavaScript most likely) and then send a request back to the server notifying it of the banner click.